# Why the use of "across"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> He was pointing at Black who had crossed to the four-poster bed and sunk onto it,
> his face hidden in one shaking hand.

Cross means "going across".
Now a room has four sides, what would be across.
I mean, if he simply walked along in a straight line,  why not "walked to the four-poster bed"?
Across has to mean something?
Maybe it imply the position with the four sides of walls.

Comment: across... *from one side to the other  opposite side.*

Comment: Though what is the difference between "go along"and "go across" here?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with wall sides as across -wall can't be adjacent or something?

Comment: "go along" means to travel the length of something (or part of the length of something), generally something longer than it is wide, like a river or corridor. You wouldn't normally go along a room unless it was very long and thin like a corridor, cloister, or gallery. "go across" implies moving through a space, so often somewhere more square or circular (not long and thin), and implies you're not next to the walls all the way, hence going across a room, park, garden, town, etc. (This doesn't really answer the question, which is about "cross" as a verb, but hopefully it is useful.)

Comment: He was presumably at the other side of the room, and he walked across the floor space to reach the bed. (That is, he _crossed the room_.)

Answer (score 5):

While a dictionary definition of 'cross' as a verb might be '*go or extend across or to the other side of (an area, stretch of water, etc.).*' it is commonly used idiomatically for any movement across a defined space. So I might cross to my desk even if my desk was very close by. It implies movement more than it implies movement in a particular direction or from one place to another.